# some special character is replace by '?' while generating pdf from html

Tags: c#, html, itext

I am trying to generate pdf from html file using itextsharp library, but I have one issue in that when I convert html into pdf, some special character of html file is replace by '?' sign. (ex €)

here is my code :

```
var elements = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, null);
foreach (var element in elements)
{    
    document.Add(element);
}
```

XMLWorkerHelper is a class of itextsharp library.
I just want that my pdf is generate same as my html file.

Comment: can you set an Encoding somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(String, String)` (which you are) then iTextSharp is going to ask the .Net runtime to figure out the contents of the file by calling [`System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx).

Per the docs, `System.Text.Encoding.Default`

> Gets an encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page

And further (emphasis mine):

> Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the ***default encoding can even change on a single computer***. Therefore, data streamed from one computer to another or even retrieved at different times on the same computer might be ***translated incorrectly***. In addition, the encoding returned by the Default property ***uses best-fit fallback to map unsupported characters to characters supported by the code page***. For these two reasons, ***using the default encoding is generally not recommended***. To ensure that encoded bytes are decoded properly, you should use a Unicode encoding, such as UTF8Encoding or UnicodeEncoding, with a preamble. Another option is to use a higher-level protocol to ensure that the same format is used for encoding and decoding.

So from the above you'll see that in the absence of any information in the file about how the raw bytes are intended to be interpreted, .Net will just use the local [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) to interpret them. What's really fun is if you move your code 100% exactly as-is to another machine you might get different results because that machine might have a different code page set.

The best solution is to avoid code pages completely. To do this, just save the file as Unicode compatible format such as UTF8 and include a BOM to explicitly declare your intentions. The BOM is optional (and frowned upon by some people) but it is also the most explicit way in the absence of other information (such as HTTP headers or post-it notes).

The second option is to just re-implement `XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList()` with your appropriate encoding. SourceForge is apparently down right now so here's the body of that method:

```
/**
 * Parses an HTML string and a string containing CSS into a list of Element objects.
 * The FontProvider will be obtained from iText's FontFactory object.
 * 
 * @param   html    a String containing an XHTML snippet
 * @param   css     a String containing CSS
 * @return  an ElementList instance
 */
public static ElementList ParseToElementList(String html, String css) {
    // CSS
    ICSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    if (css != null) {
        ICssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(css)));
        cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);
    }

    // HTML
    CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(FontFactory.FontImp);
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.AutoBookmark(false);

    // Pipelines
    ElementList elements = new ElementList();
    ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
    CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.Parse(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html)));

    return elements;
}
```

The second to last line of code that starts `p.Parse` is what you'd want to change. Since we don't know what the bytes of your file are (and neither does your computer, apparently) we can't tell you what to switch the encoder over to.

Just to wrap up, this actually isn't an iTextSharp problem at all, this is actually the default behavior of the .Net runtime. iTextSharp is just using system default in the absence of information.

Answer (score 0):

**p.parse(new StringReader(html));**

this worked for me